# PHP how to return errors if I use functions to close the browser connection

Tags: php, connection

using a function to close the connection with the browser while another process continues, is it possible to have the errors of the process in execution in a modal window opened by AJAX?

Now in the modal window I get are the value of $outputText even if the process stops.

Here are the details:
function to close browser connection

```
function closeOutput($outputText)
{
        set_time_limit(0);
        ignore_user_abort(true);
        ob_start();
        echo $outputText;
        $size = ob_get_length();
        header("Connection: close\r\n");
        header("Content-Encoding: none\r\n"); 
        header("Content-Length: $size",TRUE);
        header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");;
        ob_end_flush();
        ob_flush();
        flush();
}
```

and this is the function of the process

```
function processmail($con,$id) 
{
  for($i=1; $i <= 20; $i++)
  {
    mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM nlarea WHERE id='$id'");
    sleep(2);
  }
}
```

these 2 functions are called from this send.php file

```
<?php
  //send.php
  foreach ($id_letter as $id)
  {
    $outputText = '<img src="/img/loader.gif" class="img-fluid" alt=""> <p class="center mt-2">Close the window, the send continues automatically</p>';
    closeOutput($outputText);
    processmail($con,$id);
  }
?>
```

The send.php is call from a AJAX

```js
     <script>
       $(document).ready(function()
       {
         $("#btnSend").click(function(e) 
         {
           e.preventDefault();
           var dataform= $("#MyCheckForm").serialize();
           $.ajax( {
             url: "send.php?id=<?=$id?>",
             method: "POST",
             data: dataform,
             success: function(data) {
               console.log(data);
               $("#myModal").modal("show");
               $(".modal-title").html('Sending in progress');
               $("#add_body").html(data);
             },
             error: function(data) {
               console.log(data);
             }
           });
         });
       });   
     </script>
```

many thanks to all

Comment: It is not clear to me for why you close the connection. And in `send.php`you close the connection for each `letter_id`, also this move is not clear to me.

Comment: Once you have closed the connection to the browser, there's no direct way for the `send.php` script to send a message to the browser. You could do it indirectly, through a file on the server, or a database, but you would need to check for errors from the browser.

Comment: @lars k. because the processmail function can last even several hours, the posted one is simplified. Yes, the closeOutput function  I can put it out of the foreach in send.php